# Using TrueQ with conditions

Tags: boolean-computation, inequalities

Say I want to ask *Mathematica* whether $|x| = x$ for all $x > 0$.

Obviously, if I try `TrueQ[Abs[x] == x]`, I get `False`, because I haven't specified that I'm talking only about the case where $x > 0$. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Assuming[x > 0, TrueQ[Refine[Abs[x] == x]]] ?

Comment: I like this method, it's very readable and intuitive. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[x, x > 0, Abs[x] == x]]`

Comment: `Simplify[Abs[x] == x, x > 0]` or `Assuming[x > 0, Abs[x] == x // Simplify]`

Comment: @Prashanth `TrueQ` is a purely programming construct and cannot be used for symbolic mathematics.  It is not affected by `Assuming`.  All it does it maps `True` to `True` and everything else to `False`.  It is meant to be used in situations where a `True` or `False` value is required but the function you're calling may return something else or (typically) return unevaluated.  E.g. `TrueQ@Positive[...]` because `Positive[x]` returns unevaluated.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the info about TrueQ. I agree that Assuming does not affect TrueQ. Thats why I added Refine[] in the answer, which had the Assumptions option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Posting this here as community wiki because we answers should not stay only as comments.

---

You have many options

### Using [`Resolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html) and [`ForAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html)

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, x > 0, Abs[x] == x]]
```

### Using [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html)

```
Assuming[x > 0, TrueQ[Refine[Abs[x] == x]]]
```

But assumptions can be placed inside `Refine`, as in

```
Refine[Abs[x] == x, x > 0]
```

### Using [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
Simplify[Abs[x] == x, x > 0]
```

### Other

Actually almost any other function that accept assumptions will do the job.

```
PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], x > 0] == x
```